# How to make desktop icons?

Tags: unity, icons, shortcuts

This isn't really a big deal or anything, I was just curios if it was possible to make an alias/shortcut for apps and move them to the desktop for easy access? I know you can pin them to the launcher, but I didn't know whether or not you could place them directly to the desktop. I like to keep my Ubuntu and my OSX extra organized so there's not a lot of stuff I keep on the desktop, but some stuff I just like easy access to. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, by creating a `.desktop` file in your desktop folder. These are simple text files, with a predefined format.

So for example you want to create a desktop icon for gedit. You open up a text editor (e.g. gedit - how ironic :)), and put this text in it:

[image: Writing a <code>.desktop</code> file]

Now the only thing remaining is making the file executable. This is very simple, just right click on the file, select *Properties*, and tick the Execute flag:

[image]

By the way, the `.desktop` file specification can be read at [Freedesktop.org].(http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).